Establish which sets $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfy subsequent properties
I found this curious (for me at least) excercise and I really don't know how to proceed to solve it. Here it is:
Establish which sets $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the subsequent properties:
a) $\text{ $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists x \in A $ $\mid$ $x \le b$ }$
b) $\text{ $\forall b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x \in A$ we have $x \le b$ }$
c) $\text{ $\forall b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists x \in A $ $\mid$ $x \le b$ }$
Honestly I really don't know where to start here... How do we deal with this kind "set theory exercises"? Could someone give me a hand?

Details:
I'm sorry to have been accused of lack of effort by @Anne Bauval and @Adam Rubinson, but I did tried to solve it: I did consider some subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but it seemed to me that it didn't lead to anything and so I thought I just didn't approached the exercise right.
Some examples:
I considered the trivial set of all Real numbers: $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$:
I found that property b isn't satisfied. In fact, if we take $b=2 \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't true that $\text{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$}$ we have $x \le b$. As an example let's take $x=3 \in \mathbb{R}$, we see that $3 \le 2$ is false.
I considered the set of all negative Real numbers: $\mathbb{R}^- \subseteq \mathbb{R}$:
I found that property b isn't satisfied. In fact, if we take $b=-2 \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't true that $\text{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^-$}$ we have $x \le b$. As an example let's take $x=-1 \in \mathbb{R}^-$, we see that $-1 \le -2$ is false.
I considered $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
I found that property b isn't satisfied. In fact, if we take $b=1 \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't true that $\text{$\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$}$ we have $x \le b$. As an example let's take $x=\frac{3}{2}=1,5 \in \mathbb{Q}$, we see that $1,5 \le 1$ is false.
I considered $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
I found that property b isn't satisfied. In fact, if we take $b=1 \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't true that $\text{$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$}$ we have $x \le b$. As an example let's take $x=2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, we see that $2 \le 1$ is false.
I considered $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$
I found that property b isn't (again) satisfied. In fact, if we take $b=1 \in \mathbb{R}$, it isn't true that $\text{$\forall x \in \mathbb{N}$}$ we have $x \le b$. As an example let's take $x=2 \in \mathbb{N}$, we see that $2 \le 1$ is false.
So I just thought to ask for a hand to better understand or set up the exercise...
I thought the point of this site was to help math amateurs to understand even apparently trivial questions, not to just archive those question claiming to "just put more effort in it".
I'm very sorry to see that I was probably wrong...

My solution
So, after the help of some of you I got to the following solution:
a) $\text{ $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists x \in A $ $\mid$ $x \le b$ }$
I found that basically every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the property as to mee it seems that for every $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we can always find $b \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \le b$. The easiest example is $A = \mathbb{R}$ itself.
Of course $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ $\mid$ $x \le b$, it is guaranteed by the fact $\mathbb{R}$ inifinitely extends towards negative numbers
b) $\text{ $\forall b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x \in A$ we have $x \le b$ }$
As discussed with some of you, the property is very restrictive and the only set  $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ satisfying it is $A = \emptyset$
c) $\text{ $\forall b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists x \in A $ $\mid$ $x \le b$ }$
I found that given any $b \in \mathbb{R}$ I can always define my set $A$ this way $\text{$A:=\{ x \mid -\infty \lt x \le b\}$ or equivalently $A:=(-\infty,b]$}$ this way I can assure that the inequality $x \le b$ holds.
So each of the infinite sets definable this way based on any $b \in \mathbb{R}$ given satisfies the property
Is this right? Are these all the sets that satisfy the properties or I'm still missing something?

With your edit, you can see that property b) is very restrictive, so you can start investigating it. Can you find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \leq b$?

i am not a fan of curt templated responses either, volunteers looking to help will encounter these all day and get tired of it but those seeking help are just formulating their own question. so wouldn't take it personally

You are expected to provide 3 distinct answers: the subset satisfying a, then the ones satisfiying b, then the ones satisfying c. Hint for b, only one single subset is acceptable...

@GeorgeCoote Don't get me wrong, nothing personal for sure... I just felt sorry  being mistaken for someone who didn't put much effort into this (with the warning and downvote included) when actually I always respected the spirit of stackexchange trying to resolve my doubts on my own before writing here...
I think a "you probably got the question wrong [...]" like Serge Ballesta wrote would have been sufficient and preferable

@eti902 Could it be $A={-\infty}$ ?
But I know $-\infty\ \notin \mathbb{R}$, thus A would not be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$... So maybe the set of the sets satisfying the b property could just be $\emptyset?$

@SergeBallesta Thank you so much, I just got the question wrong... So could it be A={−∞} for property b?
But I know $-\infty\ \notin \mathbb{R}$, thus A would not be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$... So maybe the set of the sets satisfying the b property could just be $\emptyset?$

@ela Yes it is only the empty set.

For your solution, in the case $a)$, there is one subset that you need to exclude. Do you see which one?

For the case $c)$, a subset is not necessarly an interval. But you have the good idea. Can you reformulate your idea?

@eti902 for the case a: perhaps it could be again $\emptyset$? Since taking a $b \in \mathbb{R}$, we can't find any $x \in \emptyset \mid x \le b$ because there simply isn't any element in $\emptyset$

For the case c: I've always been told that sets can be defined either in the (being $A$ our set to be defined) $A := {...}$ form or using intervals, i.e. $A := [a,b]$ as an example. Is this wrong?
Maybe I could change the second definition writing $A:={x \mid x \in (-\infty, b)}$ basically saying A is composed of all the $x$ inside that interval?...

You have already found the solutions for the questions a and b.
For the question c the requirement means that A has no minorant. So A must be an infinite subset of $\Bbb R$ containing a sequence having $-\infty$ for limit. Examples of such subsets include (non limitative list):

$\Bbb R_-$
any interval $(-\infty; a)$ or $(-\infty; a]$ where $a$ in an arbitrary real number
$\Bbb Q_-$ or $\Bbb Z_-$
$\{u_i, i\in\Bbb N\}$ where the sequence $u$ verifies $\lim u = -\infty$


Thank you for your help, now it's much clearer


a) is equivalent to: $$\exists x\in A\quad\exists b\in\Bbb R\quad x \le b.$$You didn't answer question a. "basically every subset of R
satisfies the property" is too vague, and your two attempts of justification are flawed: "for every $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we can always find $b \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \le b$" is not well-formed (who is $x$?), "$\exists b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ $\mid$ $x \le b$" (we want $x\in A$), "it is guaranteed by the fact $\mathbb{R}$ inifinitely extends towards negative numbers" (irrelevant).The answer to question a) is: every nonempty subset of $\Bbb R$. This condition is necessary to achieve $\exists x\in A\dots$, and it is sufficient, since a solution for $b$ is then for instance $b=x$.
b) is equivalent to: $$\forall x\in A\quad\forall b\in\Bbb R\quad x \le b.$$Your guess for b) is correct but you did not prove it. $A=\varnothing$ is necessary because there is no real number $x$ such that $\forall b\in\Bbb R\quad x \le b$, in other words: $\forall x\in\Bbb R\quad\exists b\in\Bbb R\quad b<x$ holds (take for instance $b=x-1$). $A=\varnothing$ is also sufficient, the statement $\forall x\in A\dots$ being then vacuously true.
c) is equivalent to $\forall b\in\Bbb R\quad\neg(\forall x\in A\quad b<x)$, rewritten for short:
$$\forall b\in\Bbb R\quad\neg(b<A),$$i.e. $A$ is not bounded from below. This is the answer. Your examples are correct but partial ($A$ is not necessarily an interval), and again, your justification is flawed: "given any $b \in \mathbb{R}$ I can always define my set $A\dots$" is not the correct approach. We want $A$ such that for every $b\in\Bbb R$ there exists $x\in A$ such that $x\le b$.

